# Open an xaml file inside a popup window in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I need to open an xaml file inside a popup window in silverlight.
In my case i am having two xaml files namely a.axml and b.axml.,
In a.xaml, there is a hyper link button and a popup tag inside it.
I have to open the b.xaml page inside that popup window on clicking the hyperlink of the a.xaml page.

This is my scenario. Pls help me to solve this issue.

thanks,

Neon

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the [Child property of the popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.child%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to be a new instance of your b.xaml class (whatever that is).

Answer (score 0):

Using Telerik controls its getting easier. But you may use second method.
On Blend I changed the template of Telerik's child window. It  seems better now

[image]

```
        HyperlinkButton link = new HyperlinkButton();
        link.Click += (s, a) =>
            {
                //With telerik
                RadWindow w = new RadWindow();
                w.Content=new UserControl();
                w.Show();
                w.ShowDialog();//Swith light and avoid access oter controls                                          

                //Without Telerik
                Popup p = new Popup();
                p.Child = w.Content as UserControl;
                p.IsOpen = true;

            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent Page XAML:

```
    <HyperlinkButton Content="HyperlinkButton" Height="23"          HorizontalAlignment="Left"          Margin="150,111,0,0" Name="hyperlinkButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Click="hyperlinkButton1_Click" />
```

Code Behind :

```
   public ParentPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void hyperlinkButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChildPage objpage = new ChildPage();
        objpage.Show();
    }
```

Here Is Pararent Page have buuton . child page load based on That button Click